# Configure double opt-in

Tags: marketing-cloud, gdpr

I've followed the steps to [create a double opt-in](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_double_optin_classiclist.htm&type=5) from a List but I didn't find the checkbox next to the list for which to define a double opt-in status. Do I have to ask Salesforce Support to enable this functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct, by default this isn't enabled for Marketing Cloud lists.

Simply create Admin Assist type of a support ticket requesting "List Double Opt-In" feature activation.